# Playing audio files in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, audio, callback

I have many small audio files, and I want to play these files one after another, not all of them at the same time. I have used the object Audio in javascript like this

```
var audio_1 = new Audio();
var audio_2 = new Audio();
var audio_3 = new Audio();

audio_1.src = "/path1";
audio_2.src = "/path2";
audio_3.src = "/path3";
```

Now I just need to call the function `play` for every object, but I need to play the `audio_1` alone, and play `audio_2` when the first one ended.

The solution I found is to test on the property `ended` of every object

```
 audio_1.ended; // returns true when it ends playing
```

I found an object `onended` inside the audio object, I thought it's a function but it's not, can someone help me and give me the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `addEventListener` instead of assigning a function to the `onended` property:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {}); // Do
audio.onended = function() {}; // Don't
```

So, a IMHO dirty way is this:

```
audio_1.play();
audio_1.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    audio_2.play();
    audio_2.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        audio_3.play();
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I can put path to files in an array, and use only audio_1, when it ends I change the src to the next one and play again , until all the elements on the array are played.

Comment: @Khalid That's the proper solution ;-)